# How to find the difference equation from system response or primitive equation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, signal-processing

If I have a system response or the primitive equation , how can i find its difference equation by mathematica?

eg:

```
h[n] = b0 a^n u[n] + b1 a^n-1 u[n-1]
H[z] = b0 + b1 z^-1 / (1- a z^-1), |z| > |a|
```

expect:

```
y[n] - a y[n-1] = b0 x[n] + b1 x[n-1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please try to be a bit clearer in your example. This will help others in understanding and solving your problem

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented internal function that does this.

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[(b0 + b1 z^-1)/(1 - a z^-1), 1/z, SamplingPeriod -> 1];

Control`DEqns`ioEqnsForm[tfm][[1, 1]]
```

> [image]